# TypeScript 2.8.3 Type must have a Symbol.iterator method that returns an iterator

Tags: typescript, spread-syntax

I am running into an error that says

```
Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

It hopes on the demarcated line:

```
class Test {
    private async do() {
        const done = [...(await this.test())]; // Here's the error
    }

    private async *test(): AsyncIterableIterator<string> {
        return;
    }
}
```

I have found a few issues in the TypeScript GitHub repository, but none seem to have helped. They all suggest adding new entries to `lib`. I am using `es6` target and have added `esnext`, `dom` and `es2018`. This has had zero effect on the error.

Do I miss more `lib` entries (which I doubt as the ones I am using are the catchall ones with everything in) or is the code I am using invalid?

Comment: Doesn't look like the spread operator is supported for async iterables: [relevant issue](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/103)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As I commented above, the spread operator is unfortunately currently unsupported for asynchronous iterators.  The relevant issue in GitHub is [tc39/proposal-async-iteration#103](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/103).

Recap from that issue (minus extraneous stuff such as "you could do it this way, oops no you can't, never mind"):

[@jedwards1211 said:](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/103#issue-233969670)

> Will array spread operator support ever be part of this proposal?

[@domenic ansered:](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/103#issuecomment-306565862)

> Not part of this proposal... Another proposal could certainly contemplate something new here.

And I don't see a proposal elsewhere (want to [start one](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/)?).  In any case, since it isn't part of even JavaScript ESNext, it most likely won't get added to TypeScript.

The most viable alternative is the `for await` syntax detailed in [@estus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50236790/2887218).  Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.  Good luck!

Answer (score 190):

this has helped me.
in tsconfig, add this :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es5", "es6", "dom", "dom.iterable"
        ]
    }
}
```

This is required for tsconfig to know which interfaces to import while transpiling your code.

dom.iterable includes all the interfaces mentioned here : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/dom.iterable.d.ts

Also thanks to @domlas for mentioning this. I already upvoted his comment so that it is treated as default reason.

Comment: @IlyaEremin
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.iterable.d.ts

Comment: I had to add `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.base.json` then it worked

Comment: @Santosh you might be working in Angular or a similar library/framework. This is rather a framework-agnostic solution.

Comment: isn't `"downlevelIteration": true,` also needed duo to es5 support?

Comment: You really only need `"dom", "dom.iterable"` but it works like a charm

Comment: @JrBriones the spread operator in the question was just introduced in es6 that time.

Answer (score 33):

I think you can get rid of the error if you **cast** "this.test()" to **string** or **array**.

My situation was different, but I think my solutions might help some fellow developers.

The error message I got was:

```
     Type 'Ingredient | Ingredient[]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' 
     method that returns an iterator
```

[image]

I tried a few ways, and the following **THREE** worked, with the **FIRST** one as the simplest:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is the most straightforward, relevant, and agnostic for others to find helpful. thank you!

Answer (score 25):

**The error "Type Object must have a Symbol.iterator method that returns an iterator" occurs when we try to use the spread syntax (...) to unpack an object in an array. To solve the error, wrap your object in an array or correct your typings.**

like this..

```
const obj = { name: 'James' };

// ⛔️ Error: Type Object must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()'
// method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)
const result = [...obj];
```

We tried to use the spread syntax to unpack the properties of an object directly into an array.

**The solution for this depends on your use case. If you want to unpack the object into an array, wrap it in an array before using the spread syntax (...).**

```
 const obj = { name: 'James' };

const result = [...[obj]];

console.log(result); // ️ [{name: 'James'}]
```

source [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-type-object-must-have-symbol-iterator-method)

Comment: This comment helped me realize what I was doing wrong

Comment: Same here. I was unnecessarily spreading an object into a function's params. The object's keys were already matching the function's single param (the param is actually an "options" object with same keys).

Comment: Why don't you quote the source you copy? [Type Object must have a Symbol.iterator method that returns an iterator | bobbyhadz](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-type-object-must-have-symbol-iterator-method "Type Object must have a Symbol.iterator method that returns an iterator | bobbyhadz")

Answer (score 9):

Despite what the syntax may suggest, async generator function isn't `async` function that returns a generator.

As [the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration#async-generator-functions) states,

> Async generator functions are similar to generator functions, with the following differences:
>
> When called, async generator functions return an object, an async generator whose methods (next, throw, and return) return promises for { value, done }, instead of directly returning { value, done }. This automatically makes the returned async generator objects async iterators.

It returns asynchronous generator, not a promise, so `await`ing it doesn't make any good.

Since asynchronous generator has `Symbol.asyncIterator` instead of `Symbol.iterator`, it's non-iterable iterator, i.e. it cannot be iterated with regular ES6 methods (`Array.from`, `for..of`, spread syntax, etc). This is the reason why `for await..of` was introduced.

The code above should be:

```
const values = [];

for await (const value of this.test()) {
  values.push(v);
}
```

The iteration over asynchronous iterator can be desugared similarly to regular iterators, the difference is that `next()` returns a promise of next value, not a value itself:

```
const iterator = this.test();
let next;
       
while ((next = await iterator.next()).done === false) {
  values.push(next.value);
}
```

Since asynchronous generator spec is a proposal, the support for async iterators in ES6 iteration methods may be subject to change.

Comment: Great answer, thank you, I was aware of `for await` but couldn't make sense of how to use that with the spread operator which @jcalz addressed so I'm inclined to accept their answer, however yours is really great too and I've upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply tag `as any[]` to your spread operator e.g.

```
 addTemplateVariable(templateVariable: string) {
    this.patchState((state: CmsState) => ({
      cms: {
        ...state.cms,
        templateVariables: [
          ...state.cms.templateVariables as any[],
          templateVariable
        ]
      }
    }))
  }
```

I came across this problem when using ngrx component store

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error while trying to iterate over the values that were yielded by an `async function*`.

Changing from

```
for (const value of myAsyncGeneratorFunction()) {
```

to

```
for await (const value of myAsyncGeneratorFunction()) {
```

Fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error trying to use the spread syntax (...) in a reducer(NgRx), you can see the following:

```js
const _ingresoEgresoReducer = createReducer(initialState, 
    on(setItems, (state, { items }) => ({ ...state,  items: [...items]})), 
    on(unSetItems, state => ({ ...state,  items: []})), 
);
```

It shows the error  "Type 'IngresoEgreso' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator." with the part  [...items]

To solve the issue I should change to

```js
const _ingresoEgresoReducer = createReducer(initialState, 
    on(setItems, (state, { items }) => ({ ...state,  items: [...[items]]})), 
    on(unSetItems, state => ({ ...state,  items: []})), 
);
```

And it works fine to me.

This solution was found at https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-type-object-must-have-symbol-iterator-method

Answer (score -32):

Error went if added

`"strict": false`

in tsconfig.json

Comment: They may not want to run with strict mode disabled.